# Files when modified appear as new files git

Tags: git, git-diff

I have a problem with git when modifying some files from the same project
Appear like new
For example, I have an a.php file

```php
-
-namespace Core;
-
-interface IKernel
-{
-    public static function Start();
-}
```

When modifying it after adding it in git, the file appears as new. It does not show me the location of the modification

```php
-
-namespace Core;
-
-interface IKernel
-{
-    public static function Start();
-}

//s
```

`git diff`

```
-<?php
-
-namespace Core;
-
-interface IKernel
-{
-    public static function Start();
-}
+<?php^M
+^M
+namespace Core;^M
+^M
+interface IKernel^M
+{^M
+    public static function Start();^M
+}^M
+^M
+//s
```

https://github.com/i74ifa/UnknownRori-PHP/commit/1459d6903c4dccf09b6992b4fe8621cd13a31a83?diff=split

Take a look at this commit for clarity

I added line 7 and it thinks I made a new file

hope it's clear

Comment: Please show the output of `git status`

Comment: modified:   app.test

In vscode there is also no problem with git status the problem is when committing some files

Comment: So then git doesn't show it as a new file? Can you tell us what the problem is exactly? Please tell us the exact sequence of commands and output, what you expected and what you observed and exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen

look the example
 >>>i update ask

Comment: You mean by "new file" you mean "it shows the entire contents as being replaced"? This is almost certainly that you changed the newlines between the two files.

Comment: When you say "_Git thinks it's a new file_" what you mean is that `git diff` shows all lines as _modified_ instead of just the one you added. If you run `git diff -w` ([ignore space changes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--w)), what do you get?

Comment: may by ): yeah yeah

Comment: The issue here is that the old file used `\r\n` as newlines whereas the updated file only uses `\n` as newlines, so effectively the end of every line in your file changed.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Is the problem with the code editor difference or what??? Do you have a solution

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you're seeing is `git diff` reporting *all* lines as modified instead of just the one you added.

If you run `git diff -w` ([`--ignore-all-space`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--w)) you should see just the new line.

This happens when your text editor saved the file with *different line endings* than it had originally. That's why all lines appear as modified.

If you didn't convert the line endings yourself by accident, you should configure your editor to keep the original line endings when saving a file.
If you're working on a team, [Editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org/) is a good way to ensure that everyone's editors is configured to use the same line endings.

Comment: thanks I will try it